# Python Sqlite3 execute falied when using placeholder in 'order by'

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

The code is as follow, looks like sqlite3 [substitution](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) in 'order by' syntax have some bug.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('student.db')
cur = conn.execute('select * from students order by :sort :order limit 10', dict(sort='age', order='desc'))

# This will get
# OperationalError: near ":order": syntax error

# If you do this, the result is NOT sorted by the age column
cur = conn.execute('select * from students order by :sort limit 10', dict(sort='age'))

# I don't know why
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call

```
cur = conn.execute('select * from students order by :sort :order limit 10', dict(sort='age', order='desc'))
```

results in the query

```
select * from students order by 'age' 'desc' limit 10
```

That would return the contents of the table sorted by the *literal* string `'age'`, which is the same for all rows so does nothing. However `'desc'` is not valid, it must be `desc` without quotes, that's why you get an error.

You should use query parameters where possible, but query parameters can't be used to supply table and column names or keywords.

In this case you need to use plain string formatting to build your query. If your parameters (in this case sort criterium and order) come from user input you need to validate it first, e.g:

```
valid_column_names = {'age', ...}
valid_sort_orders = {'asc', 'desc'}
sort = get_sort_column_from_user_input()
order = get_order_from_user_input()
# use user supplied value if valid, else use a default
sort = sort if sort in valid_column_names else 'age'
# validate sort orders
order = order if order.lower() in valid_sort_orders else 'asc'

query = 'select * from students order by {sort} {order} limit 10'.format(sort=sort, order=order)
cursor.execute(query)
```